# How to create VM using latest .NET SDK for Azure

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-.net

I am creating a simple WPF application to do certain task from the application e.g.creating VM, getting list of cloud services,etc. I have installed **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management** packages from Nuget and able to get list of VMs and other things. However i couldn't get my head around creating a resource say a VM in Azure using the latest .NET SDK. I went through some links:

http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601419/How-to-manage-Azure-IaaS-Programmatically

But I wasn't able to get the new SDK to work for creating a VM. Also the SDK is continuously getting updated and some old tutorials aren't that helpful.It would be great if someone can share how to create a VM using the latest .NET SDK.

The closest I could reach is using **ComputeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.CreateAsync**, but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-arm-deployment/

Comment: @Peter In the tutorials you mentioned above, I still have to use PowerShell for certain tasks.Also I have to add the application to Azure AD. My scenario is that I am authenticating using a Management certificate and I am able to get the list of resources, but creating a resource using the new sdk is still confusing for me. Anyways I will still try to extract important things from the tutorial you mentioned. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you looking for code sample in C# to create Azure VM in classic mode? What is the nuget version you use for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute?

Comment: When you say you couldn't get `ComputeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.CreateAsync` to work, what errors were you getting? can you share the code you used?

Comment: If you are building a new application, I'd recommend targeting Azure Resource Manager (ARM) APIs as mentioned by Peter via https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-arm-deployment/.

The management certificate you are using is only going to work with Azure Service Management, not ARM.

The only thing you need PowerShell for is creating the Azure Active Directory Application / Service Principal. This is a 1 time activity. The Service Principal is analogous to your management certificate.